# Conda says package is already installed but doesn't list it and won't install it again. Python code can't import the library

Tags: python, pip, conda

Conda says the package is already installed and will not install it again, but when I list the packages in the environment, there are no packages installed.

When I try to import the package in a notebook file, it fails.
[image]

Running a terminal shell launched from JupyterLab:

1. Use pip to uninstall bashplotlib - **that works**
2. Use Conda to activate an environment -- **That works**
3. Use Conda to install bashplotlib -- It fails because it's already supposedly installed
4. Use Conda to print the packages installed in the Conda environment -- **There are none listed**

> ```
> PS C:\Users\nicomp> pip uninstall bashplotlib
> Uninstalling bashplotlib-0.6.5:
>   Would remove:
>     c:\users\nicomp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bashplotlib-0.6.5-py2.7.egg-info
>     c:\users\nicomp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bashplotlib\*
>     c:\users\nicomp\anaconda3\scripts\hist-script.py
>     c:\users\nicomp\anaconda3\scripts\scatter-script.py
>     c:\users\nicomp\anaconda3\scripts\scatter.exe
> Proceed (Y/n)? y
>   Successfully uninstalled bashplotlib-0.6.5
> PS C:\Users\nicomp> conda activate fooEnvironment   
> PS C:\Users\nicomp> conda info --envs
> # conda environments:
> #
> base                  *  C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3
> bashplotlibEnvironment     C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\bashplotlibEnvironment
> condaTestEnvironment     C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\condaTestEnvironment
> fooEnvironment           C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\fooEnvironment
> jupyterlab-debugger      C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\jupyterlab-debugger
> microservices            C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\microservices
> ml                       C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\ml
> someEnvironment          C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\someEnvironment
> zzz                      C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\zzz
>     
> PS C:\Users\nicomp> conda install -c conda-forge bashplotlib 
> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: done
>
> # All requested packages already installed.
>
> PS C:\Users\nicomp> conda list -n fooEnvironment
> # packages in environment at C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\fooEnvironment:
> #
> # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
> PS C:\Users\nicomp>
> ```

Comment: Looks like your `conda activate` command is not behaving. I.e., the `conda info --envs` shows **base** is still activated. More reliable is to always specify the target environment, e.g., `conda install -n fooEnvironment -c conda-forge bashplotlib`

Comment: Wow! is that a bug? I tried that and it worked!

Comment: Maybe? If it is, it's shell or terminal specific. I don't use PowerShell or Jupyter terminal, but many people seem to have issues with PowerShell and Conda activation. Unfortunately, I get the sense that there isn't a consistent Windows + Conda expert who is outspoken on StackOverflow and gives canonical-quality answers for that subset of the user community. (someone prove me wrong and I'll be happy to upvote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Activation Failing

From the `conda info --envs` output, it indicates that the `conda activate` command is not working, since the output shows that **base** is still activated (that's what "`*`" indicates). That is, despite the efforts, the package is getting installed in **base**.

#### Specifying Target Environment

I can't answer why the environment activation is broken (this can be specific to PowerShell or the Jupyter terminal - try searching), but I can at least recommend a more robust installation command. Rather than relying on environment activation, most Conda commands support specification of the target environment using the `--name,-n` or `--prefix,-p` flags. In this case,

```bash
conda install -n fooEnvironment -c conda-forge bashplotlib
```

would work no matter what environment happens to be activated.

I'd encourage this as a good habit to adopt because it makes the command less context-sensitive.